# SQL Server Agent job returns a failure status message after the job succeed.

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, jobs

We have a sql server agent job which runs every day on sql server 2008R2. The job has been running for years and had no issues before; and nothing has been changed recently.

Two weeks ago, the job started sending a failed job email once every 2 or 3 days. It also logs a failed job status both on sql server agent job history  as well as event viewer. However, the job is successfully executed because we are getting a successful report from the application side all the time.  Can someone have any idea how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Did you made sure logic of job did not changed, I mean the next step when job succeeds is  quite job reporting success not quit job reporting failure.

Comment: Yes, it was set up as to quit the job reporting success. As I said, the job has been configured and running for years and nothing has been changed recently. Even now the job is scheduled to run daily, most of the time works perfect but sending  this failed/ error message once every 2 or 3 days.

Comment: Does the job retry after the failure?

Comment: NO, retry attempt is setup to 0.

Comment: What message does the job send to you? if you check in job history, what is the error message?

Answer (score 2):

For me This looks a clash between job schedules. if the job is executing one day and fail the next day,there may be other job running that might contradict with this schedule. you might have to check all your job schedules and take appropriate action accordingly.

This link might help you to check all the jobs schedules running in your server. 
http://www.sqlprofessionals.com/blog/sql-scripts/2014/10/06/insight-into-sql-agent-job-schedules/